# Where has my logic gone wrong in my attempt to implement a sudoku solver in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, backtracking, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

```js
const N = 4;
const fourbyfour = [
  [1, 0, 0, 4],
  [3, 4, 1, 2],
  [2, 1, 4, 3],
  [4, 3, 2, 1],
];

function solve(board) {
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        for (let k = 1; k < N + 1; k++) {
          board[i][j] = k;
          if (isValidBoard(board)) {
            if (isSolved(board)) return board;
            else solve(board);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}

function isSolved(board) {
  let cells = [];
  for (let row of board) {
    cells.push(...row);
  }
  return !cells.includes(0);
}

function isValidBoard(board) {
  // Check rows are valid
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const row = board[i].filter((cell) => cell !== 0);
    if (new Set(row).size !== row.length) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Check columns are valid
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    let column = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (board[j][i] !== 0) column.push(board[j][i]);
    }
    if (new Set(column).size !== column.length) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  const root = Math.sqrt(N);
  // Check each grid
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i += root) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j += root) {
      const square = [];
      for (let k = i; k < i + root; k++) {
        for (let l = j; l < j + root; l++) {
          if (board[k][l] !== 0) {
            square.push(board[k][l]);
          }
        }
      }
      if (new Set(square).size !== square.length) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.table(solve(fourbyfour));
```

solve() keeps on returning undefined.
I'm fairly certain the issue is in the solve function, and not related to isSolved() and isValidBoard(). The solve function is getting the correct board, if I console.log the board instead of returning it, the correct board gets printed, but for some reason it isn't getting returned.

Comment: I feel like adding a few curly brackets could help you solve the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you return the value here, i.e. `else solve(board);` should be `else { return solve(board); }`?

Comment: thanks! you're right. @user2740650

Answer (score 2):

You are never returning the value of your recursion. You need to return from the *second* time you enter `solve`.

Also, `console.table` does not seams to be working in the snippet

```js
const N = 4;
const fourbyfour = [
  [1, 0, 0, 4],
  [3, 4, 1, 2],
  [2, 1, 4, 3],
  [4, 3, 2, 1],
];

function solve(board) {
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        for (let k = 1; k < N + 1; k++) {
          board[i][j] = k;
          if (isValidBoard(board)) {
            if (isSolved(board)) {
              return board;
            } else {
              return solve(board);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 'test';
}

function isSolved(board) {
  let cells = [];
  for (let row of board) {
    cells.push(...row);
  }
  return !cells.includes(0);
}

function isValidBoard(board) {
  // Check rows are valid
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const row = board[i].filter((cell) => cell !== 0);
    if (new Set(row).size !== row.length) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Check columns are valid
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    let column = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (board[j][i] !== 0) column.push(board[j][i]);
    }
    if (new Set(column).size !== column.length) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  const root = Math.sqrt(N);
  // Check each grid
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i += root) {
    for (let j = 0; j < N; j += root) {
      const square = [];
      for (let k = i; k < i + root; k++) {
        for (let l = j; l < j + root; l++) {
          if (board[k][l] !== 0) {
            square.push(board[k][l]);
          }
        }
      }
      if (new Set(square).size !== square.length) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(solve(fourbyfour));
```